# How to know Workload Automation Agent's FTP site

Tags: scheduler, ibm-cloud, workload

I would like to ftp put csv.file to my Workload Automation Agent which is provisioned by Bluemix. Regarding to the following Bluemix Doc, I think that I can ftp put files to the agent by the following command.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/WorkloadScheduler/index.html
*To upload and download files to and from the Workload Automation Agent, you can use the curl command line.* 
`curl -T DATA.DAT ftp://myftpsite.com/dat/ --user myname:mypassword`

But there is no information how to know the ftp site. I think that VCAP_SERVICES values of a Workload Scheduler Service are for the connection to the service instance, not to the agent. I tried to ftp access to the url of the VCAP_SERVICES, but got the connectionn error.

Does the Bluemix Doc mean that a Workload Automation Agent is a FTP Client(No1), not FTP Server(No2) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation is referring to your own ftp server, and "myftpsite.com" is just an example/placeholder.
The ftp server/account could be for example:
- your own ftp server
- a ftp service from an account registered on a shared hosting

and so on.

Then you can replace myftpsite.com with your ftp service (using hostname or IP), myname and mypassword with the service account related data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please let me confirm. Can't we ftp put files to the Workload Automation Agent which is auto-provisioned by Bluemix Workload Scheduler Service? I think that we can't configure ftp settings in the auto-provisioned Workload Automation Agent. So is it collect that we can use curl's ftp protocol only for the Agent installed locally?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your last questions.
Anyway the Workload Scheduler Service allows you to create an agent/process/service which could retrieve/upload data using FTP protocol from/to an EXTERNAL storage.
Workload Scheduler Service doesn't provide any other FTP functionality, like FTP server service.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understood that the agent can be a FTP Client, not a FTP Server. I misunderstood that the agent can be a FTP Client.